# SQLite select all records for today and previous day

Tags: android, sqlite, date, select

I have the following table in my database:

```
    database.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_LOGS + " (" 
            + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement," 
            + COLUMN_ID_DAY_EXERCISE + " integer not null,"
            + COLUMN_REPS + " integer not null,"
            + COLUMN_WEIGHT + " real not null,"
            + COLUMN_1RM + " real not null,"
            + COLUMN_DATE + " integer not null"
            + ")");
```

I store a unix timestamp in the COLUMN_DATE field (integer).

Now I have the following function which grabs all of the records:

```
public Cursor fetchCurrentLogs(long dayExerciseDataID) {
    // where day = today
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + "," + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_REPS + ", " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_WEIGHT + " " +
            "from " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_LOGS + " " +
            "where " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID_DAY_EXERCISE + " = '" + dayExerciseDataID + "'", null);
    if (cursor != null) { cursor.moveToFirst(); }
    return cursor;
}
```

Now what I want to do, is I want to make this function only grab the records for today.

Then I want to make another function exactly the same, however instead of getting the records for today, I want it to get the records for the previous day. By previous, I mean the most recent day that has records that is not today. So it could be yesterday, or 3 days ago, or a month ago.

I know in MySQL you can do something like this for the current day:

`where date_format(from_unixtime(COLUMN_DATE), '%Y-%m-%d')= date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d')`

What is the equivalent to this for SQLite?

Also, can anyone help me with the where clause for the previous day as mentioned above?

Thanks so much.

Comment: what is the value in COLUMN_DATE ? is that in unix timestamp?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myDate >= date('now','-1 day')"; 
Cursor mycursor = db.rawQuery(sql);
```

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT * from Table1 where myDate = (select max(myDate) from Table1 WHERE myDate < DATE('now') )
```

Comment: I need to only select the records for the previous day, not all previous days. Know what I mean? So lets say I have entries in the database for today, and 3 days ago, and 6 days ago, I want one function to get the records for today, and the other function to get the records for 3 days ago.

Comment: Hi I need to fetch records of last 5 minutes of current date then how can I achieve this? @Yaqub

Answer (score 7):

See the [date/time functions documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE myDate >= date('now', '-1 days')
  AND myDate <  date('now')
```

Answer (score 0):

May be It is too late but, it can help someone. I am not doing differently as previous developers, I just wanted to put my version and probably it is not even the best...

```
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+Your_table+" 
WHERE ("+Column_1+" = "+Value_For_Column1+" AND date("+Your_Column_With_Time_Values+") == date('now')) AND 

"+Some_Other_Column+" = "+Some_Other_Value+" OR "+Some_Other_Column+" = "+Some_Other_Value+" ORDER BY "+Your_Column+" DESC";
```

If there could be some mistake it could be easily due to string concatenation.
Thank you!!

Answer (score -2):

Don't do the conversion in your SQL statement.  Do the conversion in your Java method.  Have your Java method create the full SQL statement. All you need is a function to convert the Java DateTime into the unix format.

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + "," + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_REPS + ", " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_WEIGHT + " " +
            "from " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_LOGS + " " +
            "where " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID_DAY_EXERCISE + " = '" + dayExerciseDataID + 
            " OR " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID_DAY_EXERCISE + " = '" + previousDay(dayExerciseDataID) +
"'", null);
```

You just need to create that previousDay method.